# Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join

I have two models **ForumThread** and **Post** set-up like this:

```
class ForumThread < ActiveRecord::Cached
    has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Cached
end

class CreateForumThreads < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :forum_threads do |t|
            t.column :thread_name, :text
        end

        add_index :forum_threads, :thread_name
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :forum_threads
    end
end

class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def self.up
        create_table :posts do |t|
            t.column :post_body, :text
            t.integer :forum_thread_id, :null => false
            t.integer :priority
        end
    end

    def self.down
        drop_table :posts
    end
end
```

I'd like to create a query that returns all forum threads where there's at least one post in each thread with priority of one. **How do I create this query?**

I've been considering something like `ForumThread.joins(:posts).select(:priority => 1)`. I'm relatively new to Active Record (and totally new to joins) so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ForumThread.joins(:posts).where(:posts => {:priority => 1})
```

see [join with conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables)

Comment: Unfortunately the results of the above query don't include columns from posts. My impression is that an inner join should include columns from both tables.

Comment: you can include other models with `includes` : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should rename `thread_id` field to `forum_thread_id` in `posts` table and add `posts_count` to `forum_threads` table.

In `Post` class add `belongs_to :forum_thread, :counter_cache => true`

Now you can query `ForumThread.where("posts_count > ?", 1).joins(:posts).where("posts.priority = ?", 1)` which will return you a collection of posts.

Comment: Updated to `forum_thread_id`. Is the `belongs_to :forum_thread` necessary? What does `:counter_cache` do?

Comment: `belongs_to` is not actually nessesary but it allows you to access a forum_thread through a post. `counter_cache` just improves the performance of your web app, by using a column in the forum_threads table which stores the number of posts associated.

Comment: Cool thanks. I was very curious about the belongs_to association.